# Unable to retrieve data from json in django

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, django-views

i have a list of brands and categories.One brand can have multiple categories.

here is the html

```
    {% for brand in brands %}
                <li><input type="radio" value="{{brand.title}}" name="brand">{{brand.title}}</li>
     {% endfor %}

              {% for category in categories %}
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="{{category.title}}" name="category" > {{category.title}}</li>
              {% endfor %}

<input type="submit" value="submit" id="brand_category">
```

here is the script

```
$('#brand_category').click(function(event){
        $("input:checkbox[name=category]:checked").each(function(){
          if($(this).prop("checked",true)){
            category.push($(this).val())
          }
        });
        parameter.push({
          brand :   $("input[type='radio']:checked").val(),
          category: category
        })

        var json = JSON.stringify(parameter);


        $.ajax({        
              type: "post",
              url: "{% url 'seller_details' %}",
              data: { 'parameter[]' : json , csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}'},
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              dataType:"json",
              success: function(data) {
                $('#loading-image').hide();
              },
              error: function(response, error) {
              }
          });
      });
```

here is the view

```
list_data = self.request.POST.get('parameter[]')
print list_data
```

i am getting data like this

```
[{"brand":"dp","category":["men","women"]}]
```

How can i collect data in django from the above format.So far i have been Unsuccessful in getting the data.
I tried with `list_data['brand']` but it prints with the following error

```
string indices must be integers
```

then i tried with

```
list_data = self.request.POST.getlist('parameter[]')
```

it threw the following error

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

What can i do.Need help.Thank you

Comment: Please don't use `[]` in the POST parameter name. That's a completely unnecessary Rails/PHP-ism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a list which contains a single dictionary you can access the dict values like so:

```
list_data = json.load(list_data)
list_data[0]['brand']
list_data[0]['category']
```

Comment: gives the same error 'string indices must be integers'

Comment: is this the correct way to do this kind of scenario? Whenever i send data..the parameter and category array retains old data as well.

Comment: @AdrafeRinzzler You should ask a new question about this issue giving the relevant context information.

Comment: Ok @doru i will do that